# What version of Jersey should I use with Glassfish 3.1 and Java 7?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, glassfish-3

After I added JAX-RS 2.1/Jersey 2.26+ libraries to my dynamic web project I got the next error:

[Glassfish error after upload WAR file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bkBZ.png)

The server is running Glassfish 3.1 with JDK 1.7.0_80

I tried to use Jersey 1.19.1 ZIP bundle but then Glassfish said:

[Glassfish error after upload WAR file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfWR3.png)

The WAR file with the latest Jersey runs perfect with Tomcat 9 and Java 8 but I need this project to run with Glassfish 3.1 and Java 7.

If you can provide a link to the correct version of Jersey I would appreciate!

This is my very fisrt question so excuse any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Jersey with `Glassfish 3` you really need to exclude all `Jersey.2` things from you war and either:

- use the bundled `Jersey.1` implementation of your `Glassfish 3.1.2.2` installation (check the /lib or /modules folders you shall see it, or online documentation)

  **EDIT**: Jersey version should be 1.11.1

  ```
    <!-- Keep 1.11.1 for Jersey which is Fish's version -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.1</version>
          <!-- <scope>provided</scope> ... set Provided scope for GF3 deployment -->
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.1</version>
          <!-- <scope>provided</scope> ... set Provided scope for GF3 deployment -->
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.1</version>
          <!-- <scope>provided</scope> ... set Provided scope for GF3 deployment -->
      </dependency>

    <!-- Etc. - Organize your dependencies accordingly ... -->
  ```
- replace the bundled `Jersey.1` libraries of your `Glassfish3` installation by another `Jersey.1` implementation/libs(if you need a fresher version) - but never expect `Jersey.2` to run with GF3.

Nonetheless you can actually write code that works with `Jersey.1` and `Jersey.2` but when you come to packaging and deployment you must build it with appropriate target JVM, dependencies and deployment descriptors - as soon as your modularization is "ok". I didn't read this post fully personnally but why not have a look [here](http://blog.alutam.com/tag/glassfish/).

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried to use Jersey 1.19.1 ZIP bundle but then Glassfish something about java.lang.IllegalStateException, so, I'm trying to find another 1.x bundle.

Comment: I added expected Jersey version in Glassfish 3.1.2.2. First to avoid any issue don't try to override its bundled version. Then try move on.

Comment: That was all I needed. I just tried with jersey server, servlet, bundle and core 1.11.1 and finally it works like a charm. Thank you sir for provide the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From Jersey latest (2.26) documentation

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#d0e560

> Since Jersey 2.26, all modules are build using Java SE 8 and there is no support for running it on older Java SE distributions.

So if you really want to use jersey 2.26 +, JDK should be 1.8+. No alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for comment.I do not want to use Jersey 2.26 exclusively, I want to use the correct version to run with Glassfish 3.1 and Java 7.